# Responsive Media queries brand logo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

I've made a full screen carousel on a responsive web-page. And added a navbar to the carousel. But this navbar have problems with responsiveness. When I shrink the web site (responsive), the navbar creats a problem about responsiveness: words are nested. How can I fix this? When I add something, I do not see anything. The latter under the carousel. Can you help me?

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
  }
.navbar {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1090;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/bQEXKz/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ANASAYFA
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">BİZ KİMİZ?</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">HİZMETLERİMİZ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">RESİM GALERİSİ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">İLETİŞİM</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <header>
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide fixed-top " data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>First Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>Second Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>Third Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hizmetlerimiz-top text-center">
          <p>NELER YAPIYORUZ?</p>
          <h3>HİZMETLERİMİZ</h3>
          <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="hizmetlerimiz-content">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="item-logo">
                      <img src="images/index.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h4>RASCHEL ÖRME MAKİNALARI</h4>
                  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                          consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus. consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="item-logo">
                      <img src="images/cozum.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h4>AYRIŞTIRICI ÇÖZGÜ</h4>
                  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                      Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus. consectetur adipiscing elit.
                      Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="item-logo">
                      <img src="images/levent.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h4>LEVENT ÇÖZGÜ</h4>
                  <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                          consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus. consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus.</p>
                      
                          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>


              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="item-logo">
                      <img src="images/boya.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h4>BOYAHANE</h4>
                  <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                          consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus. consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Suspendisse iaculis varius cursus.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
    


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what you want? Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by "words are nested"? "When I add something, I do not see anything. The latter under the carousel." is also not clear, please do your best to clarify what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Remove `fixed-top` class from the `<div id="carouselExampleIndicators">`.

Replace this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide fixed-top" data-ride="carousel">
```

With this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```